# Is there a way to add security constraint to a file handler in WildFly?

Tags: java, file, jsp, wildfly, handler

In my Java EE web app, I have defined file handlers for multiple locations on disk. For example,

```
<location name="/ReportsProcessingPath" handler="reportsProcessingPath"/>
```

and the corresponding handler as,

```
<file name="reportsProcessingPath" path="${REPORTS_PROCESSING_PATH}"/>
```

The variable `REPORTS_PROCESSING_PATH` is defined in an Env file, and points to a path on disk.

These are used to download reports generated dynamically. Generated reports are placed in that path on disk, and an `<a>` tag is placed on the front end JSP page with the `href` attribute set to the file path (containing the file handler, of course). For example,

```
<a href="/ReportsProcessingPath/myfile.zip" download>Download report</a>
```

Right now, all users on the website, whether authenticated or non-authenticated, can download this file if they know the complete path to it, including the handler name.

I want to allow only authenticated users to be able to access this file.

I tried defining a security constraint in `web.xml` as,

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ReportsProcessingPath</web-resource-name>
        <description>Declarative security tests</description>
        <url-pattern>/ReportsProcessingPath/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But this does not work. The file is still downloadable by non-authenticated users.

Is there a way to require authentication before accessing resources defined in file handlers?

If not, what is the easiest way to transition this setup to a state where authentication will be required before accessing these resources?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you define at least one `<security-role>` in your web.xml ?

Comment: Yes. <security-role><role-name>*</role-name></security-role>

Comment: Can you put your **complete** web.xml (ie with the `login-config`part) ?